# GNU parallel environmental variables separated from input

Tags: parallel-processing, snakemake, gnu-parallel

I have a problem which I think should be very easy to fix, but I for some reason I cant solve it..
I am using GNU parallel inside of Snakemake to perform some variant calling.

My input file (`contigs.txt`) looks something like this:

```sh
GL000207.1
GL000226.1
GL000229.1
GL000231.1
GL000210.1
GL000239.1
GL000235.1
```

The command which ultimatly gets executes looks something like this:

```sh
         "name=$(bash get_name.sh normal_recal.bam) \n"
         
         "cat {input.contigs} | "
         "env_parallel --env name --jobs {threads} "
         "'({input.GATK} Mutect2 -I {input.tumor} -I {input.normal} "
         "-R {input.reference} -normal $name "
         "--native-pair-hmm-threads 4 "
         "-L {{}} --germline-resource {input.gnomAD} "
         "-O {input.path}/{wildcards.sample_id}/{{}}.somatic.vcf "
         "--f1r2-tar-gz {input.path}/{wildcards.sample_id}/{{}}.f1r2.tar.gz) &> {log.err}.{{}}.err' \n"
```

If I execute this script in my interactive terminal every thing works as expected. However when I am trying to execute it inside snakemake, the program just ends without an error. I think I have tracked down what the problem is using this simple example:

`cat contigs | env_parallel --env name --jobs 4 'echo $name'`

This prints something like this:

```
sample_tumor GL000207.1
sample_tumor GL000226.1
sample_tumor GL000229.1
sample_tumor GL000231.1
```

I think that the problem is, that the input variable also gets passed to the `$name` variable, which causes the program to crash.
I was wondering how I can achieve, that only the the actual `$name` (i.e. here `sample_tumor`) gets passed. So the output of the above example would be

```
sample_tumor 
sample_tumor 
sample_tumor 
sample_tumor
```

Cheers!

Comment: To avoid the `{{}}` you can use `-I ++` and then use `++` instead of `{}` in GNU Parallel. What is the output of `env_parallel --dryrun ...`?

Comment: I currently cannot access the cluster to check what the exact output is. But I remember that the output was exactly what I expected it to be. If I copied one of the "dryrun commands" and executed them manually, everything worked as expected.

Comment: This is one more reason why you should make an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `(gatk Mutect2 -I normal_recal.bam -R genome.fa -normal sample_buffy-coat11-01 --native-pair-hmm-threads 4 -L phiX174 --germline-resource af_only_processed_gnomad_with_head.vcf.gz -O phiX174.somatic.vcf --f1r2-tar-gz phiX174.f1r2.tar.gz) &> logs/Mutect2.phiX174.err`
This is one of the commands the `dryrun` outputs. The others only differ in the contig Mutect2 operates on. Like I said, if I copy past this command in my terminal, it works as intended.

Comment: Your command is not an MCVE. You have not included all the files that you are using, so I cannot run that exact command on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my guess regarding the error was wrong. I think I miss used `env_parallel`.
This code solved my problem.

```sh
         "name=$(bash get_name.sh normal_recal.bam) \n"
         "export name \n"
         "cat {input.contigs} | "
         "parallel --jobs {threads} "
         "'({input.GATK} Mutect2 -I {input.tumor} -I {input.normal} "
         "-R {input.reference} -normal $name "
         "--native-pair-hmm-threads 4 "
         "-L {{}} --germline-resource {input.gnomAD} "
         "-O {input.path}/{wildcards.sample_id}/{{}}.somatic.vcf "
         "--f1r2-tar-gz {input.path}/{wildcards.sample_id}/{{}}.f1r2.tar.gz) &> {log.err}.{{}}.err'"
```